# Won't Vimeo.com Run out of ID's very soon?

Tags: video, uniqueidentifier, vimeo

I recently noticed that the Vimeo id's are a string of 8 integers. That means that, at most, the scheme can accomodate 10^8 videos - or 100 Million Videos. Sure, that's a huge number, but still very very finite. Won't they run out of space very soon? Do I have to plan my applications for when they add more integers or if they change to letters and integers or something? Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Depends. What would you do when you get to 99,999,999? I'd just use 100,000,000 personally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are [videos with less than 8 digits](http://vimeo.com/10000), so it would seem they're just increasing the number by 1 for each video. You should in other words definitely plan for a 9'th digit.

Personally, I'd store the whole URL for videos as a string, which would let you handle any future video numbering scheme they can think up. Counting on them always being numeric for ever is probably not a good idea, everybody seems to be doing vanity URL's by now :)

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. But the problem is not storage, rather parsing the Vimeo embed code to get information/thumbnails etc. It works great if I know all I need to do is substr(string, 0,8) to get out the video id, but I'm not sure what' I'll do when they start adding digits...

Answer (score 5):

No, they won't. They can just add more digits if necessary.

Also note that Vimeo's URIs are largely conforming to the W3C's recommendations for URIs in that they don't reveal internal implementation details - so you cannot say for certain that video IDs truly are 8-digit integer strings.

Answer (score 1):

Official answer from `Vimeo` is that they do not have plans to change identification that is currently exists:

[Will Vimeo video id always be a number?](https://vimeo.com/forums/topic:267078)

Also, this information can be useful for establishing numeric storage of vimeo ids:

[How many digits in video id numbers?](https://vimeo.com/forums/topic:51576)